# why (1 < 1 < 1) returns true in C++?

Tags: c++

I came across this riddle some days ago

```
main ()
{
    cout << (1 < 1 < 1  ? "true" : "false") << endl;
}
```

I can't figured out why on the earth it returns true. I was expecting false.

Even more :

```
cout << (2 < 2 < 2  ? "true" : "false") << endl;    // returns true
cout << (0 < 0 < 0  ? "true" : "false") << endl;    // returns false
cout << (-1 < -1 < -1  ? "true" : "false") << endl; // returns false
cout << (-2 < -2 < -2  ? "true" : "false") << endl; // returns false
```

it seems that it returns true for values strictly bigger than 0 and false otherwise.

Anyone has a explanation for this ? thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate question. But it's because `(1 < 1) < 1` is true and `(0 < 0) < 0` is false. Since `1 < 1` is false, `false < 1` is true.

Comment: I recall hearing about a language where x < y < z has the common mathematical meaning, not the surprising one that most computer languages give it. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: @john Probably python.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `1 < 1 < 1` is parsed as

```
(1 < 1) < 1
```

Here, `1 < 1` is `false`, which is converted to `0`, yielding

```
(0) < 1
```

which is true.

Comment: Downvoter (or anyone else): what's wrong with this answer? If there's a problem I'll gladly remove it.

Answer (score 2):

`1 < 1 < 1` is parsed as `(1 < 1) < 1`.  So, from the left ....

`1 < 1` is `0` (false)

`0 < 1` is `1` (true)

`1 ? "true" : "false"` is `"true"`.

And so on.

Of course, the *real* lesson here is that code like this has no place in a real-world program.  You should strive for readability ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all take into account that according to the integral conversions

> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and
>   the value true is converted to one.

The relational operator < groups left to right. Thus this expression

```
1 < 1 < 1
```

can be written like

```
( 1 < 1 ) < 1
```

Subexpression

```
1 < 1
```

yields `false`

So after its evaluation the expression will look like

```
false < 1
```

that is converted to

```
0 < 1
```

and as result yields `true`

As for example this expression

```
0 < 0 < 0
```

that is equivalent to

```
( 0 < 0 ) < 0
```

then

```
0 < 0
```

yields `false` the same way as for the preceding example. And you get

```
false < 0
```

that in turn is converted to

```
0 < 0
```

and again yields `false`.

In case when negative integer values are used as for example

```
-1 < -1 < -1
```

then

```
-1 < -1
```

yields `false`. In this expression

```
false < -1
```

false is converted to 0

```
0 < -1
```

and you get again `false`

Comment: Thanks Vlad for your detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

- (1<1<1) will return true because,

  Internally compiler made grouping like this **((1<1)<1)**.

  So, First it will execute,

  ```
  (1<1)
  ```

  above condition become false so it will set 0.
- So new condition is (0<1)

  ```
  (0<1)
  ```

  which will become true so it will return true.